# Magento /catalog/product/view.phtml cache issue

Tags: magento, caching, php

I'm having an issue with a Magento site. 
I've setup a new theme, and I'm trying to edit the Product page/template.
I'm editing this file;

```
/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

I've got the Template hints enabled, so I know that I'm definitely editing the correct file. However, changes that I make don't come through to the frontend of the site so I'm assume there's some sort of cache problem here?

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
Cache is disabled, been flushed and files deleted from var/cache.

Comment: Have you disabled cache (Sytem->Cache Management).Try deleting all files inside var/cache folder

Comment: Sorry - Yes. Already done that, cache is disabled, been flushed and files deleted. Should of added that in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the System > Tools > Compilation Enabled? I had a similar issue earlier today that got resolved by re running the compilation process. Also make sure you have the theme in question set correctly in System > Design.

Comment: Just ran the compilation, didn't make a difference - The view.phtml is still not showing my edit/s
The System > Design is set to the correct theme, and the template path hints point me to the file that I am editing

Comment: What type of edits did you make? Are you trying to add an additional phtml block? If so you need to declare it in the layout xml

Comment: I've just changed the <h1> tag for now, until I can get this problem solved.

Comment: Like I mentioned above have you set the website design to your new theme? Also what is the path of the file you are editing. Are you editing the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml?

Comment: I have set the design to use my theme in System > Design.
The file I'm editing is /app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
This is also the file that the template hints point to

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that the section you're editing may lie within a conditional statement (IE: if/else)?  If you give an example of what code you're adding and where it may help determine whether this is at fault.